# VB script error in ArcGIS 10.2, error '438', esriCore.Editor and esriFramework.ICommandBar

Tags: vbscript, arcgis

Many thanks if someone can advise what setting to check and what we can try.

Errors occur when VB script developed in ArcGIS 9.2 running on ArcGIS 10.2.

Run-time error '438' 
Object doesn't support this property or method.

[image: Error Message]

[image: Code 1]

[image: Code 2]

Comment: That is not VB.NEt code - the title says VBScript, so if that is what it is, many thanks of you would fix the tags

Comment: Maybe `Application` is empty or not an IApplication object. Can you place something like `MsgBox TypeName(Application)` before the yellow lines? (Note: ArcGIS may not allow MsgBox; in that case, you replace it by something else that prints or shows the argument to you.) This will tell you if `Application` has the correct value. Or ask the Visual Basic debugger - if ArcGIS has one - to show you the value of `Application`. (I am unfamiliar with ArcGIS...)

Comment: I tried
    Dim pApp as IApplication
    Set pApp = Application
Error occurs at the value assignment. However, you may see such sample at http://www.socsci.flinders.edu.au/geog/sisl/ESRI_Library/Developing_with_ArcObjects/Desktop_Developers_Guide.pdf (see page163)